# LGA1150 CPU on LGA1155 MoBo?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, sockets

My motherboard fried and I am looking for an identical replacement. Only, the motherboard is an Acer H81H3-AM V1.0 with socket 1155 according to specs, and CPU is an i5-4460, socket LGA1150. Is this normal ? Are these two normally compatible or is there a mistake.

Comment: Where did it say they were compatible? It sounds like they are not identical motherboards with different sockets so that should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

> The motherboard is an Acer H81H3-AM V1.0 with socket 1155 according to specs

Based on my research, the `Acer H81H3-AM` is an LGA 1150 motherboard, not an LGA 1155 motherboard.  Which means the motherboard is compatible with an i5-4460.

[image]

> Are these two normally compatible or is there a mistake.

Yes, they are indeed compatible with one another.  Yes, your specification source for the motherboard appears to be incorrect.

> Knowing the i5-4460 is 1150, and if the 1155 and 1150 aren't compatible

**LGA 1155 and LGA 1150 are not compatible with one another, but that does not matter since H81 is a Haswell chipset, and ALL Haswell motherboards are LGA 1150.**  The M2632G is an Acer desktop computer, with an 1150 Pentium G3250, which is an LGA 1150 processor.

Comment: **Due to a member of this community who decided to serial downvote my answers I have decided to convert this into a community wiki.**

Comment: The system would have caught it and reversed it...

Comment: @CanadianLuke - The system might still reverse it (I certainly still have 3 downvotes in my reputation history).  However, the user only issued 3 votes, which will unlikely be caught and reversed